# User register with OTP via email (verfification code)

Tags: emails

I'm using Drupal 8 and I have the following requirement:

Once a user register, before logging in, they need to input a one time verification code received via email and NOT SMS.

I've used the module (https://www.drupal.org/project/otp_verification) and it works (despite the fact that it doesn't allow any email customization, identity wise), but it needs a liscence, which right now, i don't have the means to acquire one.

Is there ANY other way to achieve the reauirement above?

Thanks guys

Comment: Not sure I follow this question, Drupal core has the option for email account verification build in. Is that what you mean? see: admin/config/people/accounts

Comment: You're right, in account settings you can set it without an OTP, which does verfiy the email, however my client wants the user to choose his own password while siging up, and then receive an email with an OTP to be entered in Drupal website before logging in, just like the above said module